# problems with installation tensorflow from source on ubuntu 16 with gpu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia

I have ubuntu 16.04
I have installed CUDA 7.5 from Ubuntu repo and cuDNN 5.1.3 for CUDA 7.5
and ran CUDA examples that works, same for pycuda
and I want to install tensorflow from source with gpu support,
tensorflow configuration is stuck on nvvm, and I can't find it in system also find isn't any helpful

```
$ find / -name nvvm*
/usr/include/nvvm.h
/usr/share/doc/nvidia-cuda-doc/html/nvvm-ir-spec
```

where can I find nvvm?

Comment: I have it here: `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/nvvm` (also check `/usr/local/cuda/nvvm`)

Comment: find would have found it, I have installed cuda from ubuntu repo

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` command is wrong. You need to quote the `-name` argument to prevent shell globbing:

```
$ find / -name 'nvvm*'
```